# Plotting the reciprocal of a sine wave in MatLab

Tags: matlab, trigonometry

I'm having difficulties trying to plot the reciprocal of a basic sine wave within MatLab.  The tutorial I'm following (not a MatLab tutorial) is plotting it by hand by placing a few points between each vertical asymptote to give you an idea of what the graph will look like.  I've tried using MatLab's `csc()` function, and the graph when plotted along side `x` is nothing like the drawn example.  The drawn example from `0` to `pi` looks similar to a big `U` and from `pi` to `2*pi` is a negative version (upside down).  Here is all the different combinations of code I've tried:

```
x = 0:0.01:100;
y = 5*csc(x); % amplitude of -5 to 5
plot(x,y)
```

Then I tried:

```
x = 0:0.01:100;
y = 1 / 5*sin(x);  % amplitude of -5 to 5 
plot(x,y)
```

Both results are dramatically different.  I was wondering if using the vector `x` was okay as I was under the impression after one of my previous posts that the standard MatLab trig functions are setup to take radians rather than degrees?

Comment: You need brackets around 5*sin(x), of course!! And yes, all functions take radians.

Comment: Thanks.  so when I create a vector to drop into a trig function do I need to convert the vector to radians?  Or does MatLab do that automatically?

Comment: Not necessarily. There are also versions of sin, cos, etc.. which take degrees. They are called sind, cosd, tand, .. Just check out the documentation for these

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this -

```
x = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
y = csc(x);
plot(x,y)
ylim([-10, 10])
```

[image]

Is that what you expected?

Comment: Thanks, its close, much closer than my attempt.  I noticed you ended the first statement `x=` with `pi*2` rather than 100.  Is this so we only see one period?  If so I was actually wondering how to do that :-)  Also, how come the y axis needs to be limited?  I thought just the `csc()` function would only have an amplitude between `-1` and `1`

Comment: Yes, I chose the x axis variables to show one period only. The `csc()` function is actually unbounded - it's the reciprocal of `sin()` has passes through zero, so `csc()` tends to infinity at any multiple of `pi`.

Comment: Thats great, thanks.  I would of thought you would of had to of worked out what `0.01` was in radians when you initialised the `x` variable, or does MatLab know what we mean?

Comment: Matlab defaults to radians - whenever you call the trigonometric functions, Matlab assumes that you are giving it radians. If you want to use degrees, you either need to manually convert by multiplying by `360/(2*pi)` or use the functions `sind()`, `cosd()` etc which assume you are providing an argument in degrees.

Comment: I see, that explains why my previous way of constructing my `x` variable was producing lots and lots of periods when passed into MatLab's trig functions.  Once I passed `0 to 360` expecting just one period, but as you stated, I was actually passing in 360 radians into a `sin()` which was why I was getting so may periods!  I'll accept your answer and leave you in piece.