# Plot sine function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to plot this equation but i'm some difficulties, some help please.
I here is what i have tried.

```
    x=[0:pi/20:4*pi];
    y= (25*sin(3)*t);
    plot (x,y)
```

Comment: Where did you use `x`? This is the first example in the documentation for [plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html#examples)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Plotting the reciprocal of a sine wave in MatLab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379798/plotting-the-reciprocal-of-a-sine-wave-in-matlab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code isn't working because `t` is undefined.  You either need to change your definition of `x` to be `t`, for example:

```
t=[0:pi/20:4*pi];
```

or you need to make your `y` a function of `x`, rather than `t`, for example:

```
y= (25*sin(3)*x);
```

I am curious if your original equation/function that you are trying to plot is `y(t)=25 sin(3 t)`.  If this is the case, then you need to change your parenthesis so that `sin` is a function of the independent variable (`x` or `t`).  This would look like:

```
y = 25*sin(3*x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign equal vector length value to `t` as of `x`.
However, I believe, you need to replace x with t in your equation.

```
y= (25*sin(3)*x);  # will plot a straight line since you have a constant sin(3)
                   # which you are just multiplying with x resulting in x verses constant x
```

I assume you want to write the equation as

```
x=[0:pi/20:4*pi];
y= (25*sin(3*x));
plot (x,y)
```

[Plot Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)

Comment: Did you try this? I don't think this is what the OP is looking for.

Comment: Yes, I tried. If the OP wants to use `t` in his equation then it works when the length of vector `t` is equal to that of `x`.

Comment: I apologize for not being more explicit in my comment. I find it very unlikely that the OP intended to plot a straight line including the constant `sin(3)`, especially when they're already using a numeric constant `25`. I find it more likely that the OP simply got the equation wrong and that they were trying to do `sin(3*<something>)` to produce a sinusoidal plot. Does that make sense?

Comment: That's awesome. Yes, it makes sense. Thanks @beaker, I appreciate your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant to get oscillations:

```
x = [0:pi/20:4*pi];
y = 25*sin(3*x);
plot(x,y)
```